# Java Collections - Print interstates sorted by population, city and state

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am working on a problem I came across in an interview.

Input contains ***Population|City|State|Interstates list***

Output needs to be sorted in descending order by population first, then alphabetically by city and state, and then the interstates need to be sorted in ascending order too.

**Sample input:**

```
27|Chicago|Illinois|I-94;I-90;I-88;I-57;I-55
83|New York|New York|I-78;I-95;I-87;I-80
15|Phoenix|Arizona|I-10;I-17;I-8
15|Philadelphia|Pennsylvania|I-95;I-76
```

**Sample output:**

```
83

New York, New York
Interstates: I-78, I-80, I-87, I-95

27

Chicago, Illinois
Interstates: I-55, I-57, I-88, I-90, I-94

15

Philadelphia, Pennsylvania
Interstates: I-76, I-95

Phoenix, Arizona
Interstates: I-8, I-10, I-17
```

Here's my approach so far. I am currently stuck in the if block where I've added a comment. I am not sure if I am going in the right direction. I am looking for a hint to take the right approach here.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();

//Outer map sorts reverse by population, inner map1 sorts by city, inner 
map2 sorts by state
Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> outerMap = new TreeMap<>
(Collections.reverseOrder());
Map<String, Map<String, String>> innerMap1 = new TreeMap<>();
Map<String, String> innerMap2 = new TreeMap<>();

while(sc.hasNextLine() && (line = sc.nextLine()).length()!=0) {

  //Ignore if input contains this character
  if(line.contains("#")) {
    line = sc.nextLine();
  }

  al.add(line);
}

for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {

  int outerMapKey = Integer.parseInt(al.get(i).split("\\|")[0]);
  String innerMap1Key = al.get(i).split("\\|")[1];
  String innerMap2Key = al.get(i).split("\\|")[2];

  String value = al.get(i);

  outerMap.get(outerMapKey);

  if(outerMap.containsKey(outerMapKey)) {


    innerMap1 = outerMap.get(outerMapKey);
    /* Logic to put values in inner maps 
    This is going to get very convoluted, not sure if I have the 
    right approach
    */
  }
  else {
    innerMap1 = new TreeMap<>();
    innerMap2 = new TreeMap<>();
    innerMap2.put(innerMap2Key, value);
    innerMap1.put(innerMap1Key, innerMap2);
    outerMap.put(outerMapKey, innerMap1);
  }
  }
```

Thank you for all your help so far. I am posting my code (working now) based on feedback here. Please take a look and suggest how it can be improved.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, List<PopulationByCityState>> map = readAndProcessInput();
    printSortedOutput(map);

}


private static Map<String, List<PopulationByCityState>> readAndProcessInput() {

    Map<String, List<PopulationByCityState>> map = readInput();
    sortByPopulationCityAndState(map);
    return map;
}

private static Map<String, List<PopulationByCityState>> readInput() {
    System.out.println("Enter input:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    Map<String, List<PopulationByCityState>> map = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

    while (sc.hasNextLine() && (line = sc.nextLine()).length() != 0) {
        if (line.contains("#")) {
            line = sc.nextLine();
        }

        populateMap(line, map);

    }
    return map;
}

private static void populateMap(String line, Map<String, List<PopulationByCityState>> map) {

    String[] s = line.split("\\|");
    String[] is = s[3].split(";");
    String key = s[0];
    PopulationByCityState p = new PopulationByCityState();
    p.setPopulation(Long.parseLong(s[0]));
    p.setCity(s[1]);
    p.setState(s[2]);
    List<String> interstates = new ArrayList<>();


    for (String aString : is) {
        interstates.add(aString);
    }

    sortInterstates(interstates);
    p.setInterstates(interstates);

    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.get(key).add(p);
    } else {
        List<PopulationByCityState> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add(p);
        map.put(key, al);
    }
}

private static void sortInterstates(List<String> interstates) {
    Collections.sort(interstates, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.split("-")[1]);
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.split("-")[1]);

            return n1 - n2;
        }
    });
}

private static void sortByPopulationCityAndState(Map<String, List<PopulationByCityState>> map) {
    for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {

        List<PopulationByCityState> list = (List<PopulationByCityState>) entry.getValue();


        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<PopulationByCityState>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(PopulationByCityState o1, PopulationByCityState o2) {
                int c;
                c = (int) (o2.getPopulation() - o1.getPopulation());
                if (c == 0) {
                    c = o1.getCity().compareTo(o2.getCity());
                }
                if (c == 0) {
                    c = o1.getState().compareTo(o2.getState());
                }
                return c;
            }
        });
    }
}

private static void printSortedOutput(Map<String, List<PopulationByCityState>> map) {

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<PopulationByCityState>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println();

        List<PopulationByCityState> list = entry.getValue();

        for (PopulationByCityState p : list) {
            System.out.println(p.getCity() + ", " + p.getState());
            List<String> interstates = p.getInterstates();
            System.out.print("Interstates: ");
            int s = 0;

            for (String is : interstates) {
                s++;
                System.out.print(is);
                if (s != interstates.size()) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Java is an **object-oriented** language. *Use it!* Create a `City` class. Each input row is a city object. You can then sort the `List<City>` you create, using a `Comparator` or by implementing `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach relies on over complicated and not meaningful structure and also uses a Comparator that will only sort the first level of the map :

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> outerMap = new TreeMap<>
(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

A finer approach could rely on using a class that represents each individual information that you need to represent a population for a state : `PopulationForState`

Here is a very simple representation of it (that is of course improvable but that should help you to understand the logic) :

```
public class PopulationForState{
  private long population;
  private String city;
  private String state;
  private List<String> interstates;
 ...
    // getters 
}
```

Add instances of them in a `List` and use a comparator that sorted them in descending order by population first, then alphabetically by city and state.
The `interstates` field may be sorted independently or directly during the sort of outer elements.
You could provide a sort method in `PopulationForState`, for example `sortInnerStates()` that sorts them in ascending order.

Personally, I would make it independently to keep the processing less coupled between.

So you could write something like :

```
List<PopulationForState> populationForStates = new ArrayList<>();
populationForStates.add(new PopulationForState(...));
populationForStates.add(new PopulationForState(...));

Collection.sort(populationForStates, Comparator.comparing(PopulationForState::population).reversed()
          .thenComparing(PopulationForState::getCity)
          .thenComparing(PopulationForState::getState);

populationForStates.stream()
                   .forEach(PopulationForState::sortInnerStates);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a structure such the one posted in above post:

```
public class PopulationForState{
 public long population;
 public String city;
 public String state;
 public List<String> interstates;
 //Do encapsulate
}
```

You can sort it with one comparator:

```
Collections.sort(populatisForStates, new Comparator<PopulationForState>(){
   public int compare(PopulationForState first, PopulationForState scnd) {
      int compare = first.population - scnd.population;
      if(compare != 0) return compare;
      compare = first.city.compareTo(scnd.city);
      if(compare != 0) return compare;
      return first.state.compareTo(scnd.state);
   }
});
```

Sorting Interstates is similar and you just need to use Collections.sort(interstates) on each instance.